# google finance tools on my website?

Tags: quotes, finance, stocks, google-finance

i am on the process of building a website execlusively for trading purposes. including live quotes and level 2 quotes. charts. user protofollio with automatic updates. news and so on.

am i allowed to use google finance tools on my website? and if yes how can i go about doing so?

thanks in advance

Comment: +1 At first, I thought this was so obvious, how can you ask but then, I tried to find that info myself ... :)

Comment: Also consider using Mergent financial APIs ( http://www.mergent.com/servius ) as a source of some of the data that Google Finance may not have

Answer (score 0):

See the [API Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/finance/api-terms.html).

Answer (score 0):

While it is good to use free API service, but note that there is a 20 minutes delay for [google "live" quotes](http://googlified.com/introducing-the-google-finance-api/).

The same goes for any other "free" quote service.

And yes, you are allowed to use them.